# Spresenseにおける24bit長での録音に関して

Tags: spresense

Arduino環境において、Spresenseで192kHz/24bit長での録音を試しています。
下記コードを実行すると、エラーで録音が開始できません。

```
void setup() {

  theAudio = AudioClass::getInstance();
  theAudio->begin();  
  theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_HIRES);
  theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC);
  theAudio->initRecorder(AS_CODECTYPE_WAV, "/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_192000, AS_BITLENGTH_24, AS_CHANNEL_MONO);

  if (theAudio->startRecorder() != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_OK) {
    puts("!!! Can't start recording !!!");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    puts("Start recording...");
  }
}
```

エラーメッセージ

```
Attention: module[11] attention id[2]/code[20] (components/filter/src_filter_component.cpp L330)

Attention!! Level 0x2 Code 0x14
ERROR: Command (0x32) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x3) Error code(0xd) Error subcode(0xffffff92)
```

AS_BITLENGTH_16では成功します。
24bitの場合、メモリのLayoutの設定などをやらないといけないのでしょうか？

#### 追記

Bootloaderですが、Arduino IDEでは1.1.0のダウンロードページに案内されますが、Bootloaderの変更は無いのでしょうか？

また、48kHz/16kHzにおいては、下記のエラーが発生します。
現状ではサポートされていないのでしょうか？

```
initialization Audio Library
Attention: module[3] attention id[2]/code[9] (objects/media_recorder/media_recorder_obj.cpp L1571)

Attention!
ERROR: Command (0x31) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x3) Error code(0x16)
Init Recorder!
Write Header!
Attention: module[8] attention id[2]/code[9] (components/capture/capture_component.cpp L597)

Attention!
ERROR: Command (0x32) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x3) Error code(0x2b) Error subcode(0x0)
Recording Start!
Error End
ERROR: Command (0x33) fails. Result code(0xf1) Module id(0x3) Error code(0x1)
End Recording
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答させていただきます。

残念ながら、現在のバージョンのSDKは、192kHz 24ビットの録音をサポートしておりません。
サポートには、もうしばらく時間がかかる見込みです。

ご不便をおかけして、誠に申し訳ありません。

**■ 2018年11月29日追記**

バージョン 1.1.1 にて 192kHz 24ビットの録音をサポートいたしました。
大変長らくお待たせいたしました。

詳細につきましては、リリースノートをご確認ください。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/releases

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答を更新いたしました。ご覧ください。

Answer (score 2):

Bootloader は、もし不安であれば、"Burn Bootloader" をもう一度実行してみてはいかがでしょうか？

私は、48kHz/16bit は普通に録音できています。

```
theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_HIRES);
```

この行を削除するか、

```
theAudio->setRenderingClockMode(AS_CLKMODE_NORMAL);
```

に変えたらうまくいくと思います。

Audio 関係のサンプルコードはリリースの度にかなり変わっているので、一度見直したほうがよいと思います。